Not able to get Windows 11 VM working on KVM with intel 13900k
This is my first time posting here in hopes I can find an answer to an issue I have been experiencing with trying to get my Windows 11 VM running on KVM with my new Intel 13900KS. To be specific, this virtual machine setup was working just fine with a 11900K before a hardware upgrade.
My setup for the VM is by passing through an Nvidia GPU to the VM along with an NVME SSD with Windows installed on it and my games. I am using virt-manager (KVM) on Arch Linux and have all the latest packages. I also utilize looking glass for seeing and interacting with the VM.
Now the problem I am currently having is with a very similar configuration, the VM will start for a second and then proceed to crash. After some testing, I found the line in the XML causing the issue is
<shmem name="looking-glass">
  <model type="ivshmem-plain"/
  <size unit="M">64</size>
  <address type="pci" domain="0x0000" bus="0x10" slot="0x01" function="0x0"/>
</shmem>

When this line is removed I have no problem running the VM, however, without it, looking glass will not work as it is required.
I have reached out to the KVM community within Discord twice now regarding this issue, however, no one there has been able to help me. It was suggested to add
<maxphysaddr mode='emulate'/> 

to the <CPU> within the config. This unfortunately did not work for me. When added, the VM will start without crashing but then fails to post. The looking glass displays the message "Guest has not initialized the display (yet)." and the CPU monitor will reflect no CPU usage as it remains as a flat line.
I would like to mention that I have followed the AcrWiki guide to PCI Passthrough via OVMF and the looking glass documentation ver closely so it was set up correctly. This would reflect with the VM working without the shmem line within the config.
I have reviewed the KVM logs, dmesg and even journalctl and the evidence points to the CPU being the issue for some reason. I have played with settings in BIOS like having XMP enabled, XMP disabled and even tried the new "intel baseline defaults" profile thinking it may be a stability issue. I made sure the VT-d was enabled, IOMMU setting was enabled and even removed two RAM sticks. All the same results. I am just at a complete loss and now considering trading this CPU in for 14900K to see if that would yield the results I am looking for.
I am not sure what would be the most appropriate method of attaching the logs to this post so I will utilize pastebin and link them below for you to see. I also included my KVM XML in case that is requested.

lirtlog without phyaddress
virtlog with phyaddress
KVM XML

I really would appreciate any help that anyone can offer. Thank you for your time!
EDIT: Changed pastbin of XML with removed UUID and Serial in case that is sensitive info.

one thing I've read is that Changing CPU configuration to host-model works

Hello Jaromanda. I have indeed tried this already and it still yields the same result unfortunately.
